# How to pass correct data from a dynamic button in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have a dynamic buttons where it produced from my database

[image]

My code for that in blade file

```
<div class="input-group col-sm-12">
      <!--start of the form-->
       <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('call.store') }}">

           {{ csrf_field() }} 

           <!--input type hidden department code below -->

           @foreach($departments as $department)
           <input type="hidden" id="dept_name" name="dept_name" value="{{ $department->dept_name }}">

           <input type="hidden" id="called" name="called" value="NO">

           <!--buttons -->    
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-fill pull-right" id="form-button-add">
           {{ $department->dept_name }}
           </button>
           @endforeach
        </form>
        <!--end-->   
 </div>
```

Whenever I click either one, they'all add a data in my call database based on the values per button. My problem is when I click the cashier button, the values that would add would be the assessments.

My code in CallController

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $dept_id = Department::select('id')
        ->where('dept_name', $request->input('dept_name'))
        ->first();

    $let = Department::select('letter')
        ->where('dept_name', $request->input('dept_name'))
        ->first();
    $number = Department::select('start')
        ->where('id', $dept_id->id)         
        ->first();

    $call = Call::create([
        'dept_id' => $dept_id->id,
        'letter' => $let->letter,
        'number' => $number->start,
        'called' => $request->input('called')
    ]);

    Department::where('id', $dept_id->id)
    ->increment('start');

    return redirect()->route('call.index')->with('success' , 'NEW CALL');
}
```

I also dd each query and found out that the values would get are the values from assessment or the last value from the foreach loop in my blade file. How could I get the value of cashier when I click the cashier button instead of assessment.

I would show my database so that you understand my question

Department Table: id, dept_name, letter, start(int, it'll increment after producing a call)

Counter: id, counter_num, dept_id

Call Table: id, dept_id, letter, number, counter_id, called

Answer (score 1):

When you click either button, they will submit their parent form. Because both are under the same form, the data from the first button will be submitted. You will have to make a separate form for each button in order to have them submit their own data.

```
<div class="input-group col-sm-12">
    @foreach($departments as $department)
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('call.store') }}">
           {{ csrf_field() }}

           <input type="hidden" id="dept_name" name="dept_name" value="{{ $department->dept_name }}">
           <input type="hidden" id="called" name="called" value="NO">

           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-fill pull-right" id="form-button-add">
               {{ $department->dept_name }}
           </button>
        </form>
    @endforeach
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating multiple submit buttons in the same form.
Add the  tag inside the loop so you have a unique form per case.

When there's multiple submit buttons inside the same form, the loop will finish and only the last results will be mapped to the buttons, thus is will submit the last information in your loop.

```php
@foreach($departments as $department)
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('call.store') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }} 

        <input type="hidden" id="dept_name" name="dept_name" value="{{ $department->dept_name }}">
        <input type="hidden" id="called" name="called" value="NO">

        <!--buttons -->    
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-fill pull-right" id="form-button-add">
           {{ $department->dept_name }}
       </button>
</form>
@endforeach
```